# How to populating matrices in the Apache Commons Kalman filter Implementation

Tags: java, gps, smoothing, kalman-filter, apache-commons-math

Background :   To give everyone some background I am trying to smoothen GPS data received from a device using Kalman filter (Apache
 Common implementation). What kind of dynamic   noises should I include
 in my implementation with respect to matrix P0, Q and R knowing that
 the only input I have apart from position(X and Y) is horizontal
 accuracy and velocity for X and Y components. This is not a constant
 velocity example since the velocity might change from one ping to
 another ping.

Implementation Library :   Apache Common
  - http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-math/userguide/filter.html

Usage :   I am only considering 2D space for now

Inputs that I have with me :
 1. latitude
 2. longitude
 3. horizontal accuracy or Horizontal Dilution of precision (HDOP) in meters/sec
 4. Time between two pings (dt) = 30 seconds

Outputs I care about
 1. new Latitude
 2. new Longitude

Calculated values :   Vx (velocity in X direction)   Vy (velocity in Y direction)   The object will be constantly moving but with
 varying velocities so I can   calculate Vx and Vy using the formulate
 V * sin(theta) and V * Cosine(theta)

How should I map my values to the Apache Common implementation.?

**Current setup :**

```
X = Initial State = [  

     {X Y X-Vel Y-Vel}

    ]  

 // I only care about X and Y coordinates so this is a 2 * 4 matrix  
 H = Observation variables = [   

     {1, 0, 0, 0},  
     {0, 1, 0, 0} 



 ]  

 // This is a 4 * 4 matrix  
 P0 = Cov(X) = [     

     {(horizontal accuracy from i/p), 0, 0, 0},  
     {0, (horizontal accuracy from i/p), 0, 0},  
     {0, 0, (some initial value for VY), 0},  
     {0, 0, 0, (some initial value for VX) }

    ]  

 // Copied this from somewhere. What values should I have in this?   //
 This is a 4 * 4 matrix  
 Q = Cov(Dynamic noise) = [          

     { Math.pow(dt, 4d)/4d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d, 0d },  
     { 0d, Math.pow(dt, 4d)/4d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d },  
     { Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 2d), 0d },  
     { 0d, Math.pow(dt, 3d)/2d, 0d, Math.pow(dt, 2d) }

    ]  

 // This is a 2 * 2 matrix  
 R = Cov(measurement noise) = [  

     { Math.pow((horizontal accuracy from i/p), 2d) , 0},  
     { 0, Math.pow((horizontal accuracy from i/p), 2d)} 

 ]  

 // This is a 4 * 4 matrix  
 A = State transition matrix =   [

     { 1d, 0d, dt, 0d },  
     { 0d, 1d, 0d, dt },  
     { 0d, 0d, 1d, 0  },  
     { 0d, 0d, 0d, 1d }  

 ]
```

Are my matrices correct for what I am trying to do? When I run them I
 keep getting  MatrixDimensionMismatchException and hence I decided to
 ask a question. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please reformat your question. No need of fancy formating. Use code formating for code, and quote formating for quotes.

Comment: I think it is unusual, but well formatted, no need to change the formatting

Comment: GPS coordinates are already heavily kalman filtered. Smoothing will make them less accurate. Think whether you might need filtering of unwanted locations instead of smoothing.

Comment: I removed the MATLAB tag as the Apache Commons Math library is a **Java** library.  It has nothing to do with MATLAB.  In addition, the code appears to be Java (i.e. `Math.pow`) so the retagging is justified.

Comment: @AlexWien - The device might be a watch which might not have a kalman filter on board the chip. Also what if pings are received from WIFI and hence I think I would need filtering.

Comment: @rayryeng - That makes sense. Thank you for removing the tag though my intention was to involve folks who have worked on Kalman filter using matlab since the matrices would be similar.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem by using the latest version of Apache Commons Math library.

It turns out that Apache Commons Math 3.2 and earlier version had a major bug
reported here : https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/MATH-1033

The problem was measNoise column dimension always had to be 1 which means matrix R should always have only 1 column

```
// row dimension of R must be equal to row dimension of H
if (measNoise.getRowDimension() != measurementMatrix.getRowDimension() ||
    measNoise.getColumnDimension() != 1) {  
    throw new MatrixDimensionMismatchException(measNoise.getRowDimension(), measNoise.getColumnDimension(), measurementMatrix.getRowDimension(), 1); 
}
```